# In asp.net web api, how to create a functionality of download a sample .xlsx file?

Tags: asp.net, file-handling

In asp.net web api, how to create a functionality of download a sample .xlsx file?
I tried the below function.

```
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadExcelFile()
    {
        string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Modules/SampleFiles/sample3.xlsx";

        
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "sample3.xlsx"
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        return response;
    }
```

I tried the below

```
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadExcelFile()
    {
        string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/Modules/SampleFiles/sample3.xlsx";
        
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "sample3.xlsx"
        };
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        return response;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the MediaType below?

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```